# The upper left corner of the iTerm2 full-screen function key disappears

Tags: macos, iterm2

I am using iTerm2 as my primary terminal.

I was making changes to the settings, and after that, the top left corner of the function button disappeared, I do not know how to change it back. I spent a lot of time on Google, but I did not get the answer.

[This link](https://media.giphy.com/media/l3dizk5gTaUpJTMOI/source.mp4) shows how it looks.

I tried to find the answer at https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/issues but did not find the answer.

Please help.

Comment: Is it reproducible? If yes, how?

Comment: @rvheddeg Yes, I quit iTerm2 and even reboot the computer ,but the function button still disappeared.

The default should look like this : http://gph.to/2mQF93B

Comment: Add this extra information in your answer. Let the users of this site see that you have done some work to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work but I found an example of someone in a similar situation- they did this: `Preferences -> Profile -> Window :and change the Style to Normal.`

Reference:
https://superuser.com/questions/783752/iterm2-2-0-unable-to-resize-the-main-window

Comment: I don't have iTerm myself but play around with the preference. As a last resort you could back up any files needed and do a complete uninstall and reinstall and that should work.